# Module name alias in go.mod

Tags: go, go-modules

Is there a way to use a shorter name representation/mapping in modules?

I have a project, with an url naming:

```
module github.com/<org>/<project>    
go 1.14
```

Would be nice to be able to do:

```
import "<short_name>/<project>/package_folder"
```

From a `go.mod`, something like:

```
module github.com/<org>/<project> => short_name
go 1.14
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, there is no way to define an alias in the `go.mod` file.

It was [proposed](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25518) but rejected for reasons explained [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25518#issuecomment-393345674).

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this recently with a poorly named internal repo. Go doesn't do this, but with some git magic you can get close.

In your ~/.gitconfig add something like this:
[url "ssh://git@github.com//"]
insteadOf = https://github.com/<go_mod_org>/<go_mod_repo>